# How to extract data from google analytics custom dimensions and metrics?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to extract data from my custom dimension and save to database.I tried this simple code.But I can't retrieve my custom data.I got this error "Unknown dimension:my custom dimension"

```
<?php
    include_once(app_path().'/gapi.class.php');

    $ga = new gapi('my email','my password');
    $ga->requestReportData('my GA Id',array('my Custom dimension'),array('my custom metrics'));

    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
      {
         echo $result;

      }

?>
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are referring to your dimensions by name. [Instead you should use](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns) `ga:dimension` and a numeric index (`ga:dimension1` to `ga:dimension20`). Similar for custom metrics.

Comment: @SupunWad, if this worked for you you might consider to "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer (I will get a few points and others will see that the problem is solved).